# easeljs sprite using multiple images for animation

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

Does anyone can advise if there is a way to load different images for different animation eg. "idle", "stun", "shoot"?

```
var data = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
    "images": ["images/Drones-Hovering-Loop-12fps.png"],
    "frames": {"regX": 0, "height": 262, "count": 25, "regY": 0, "width": 250},
    "animations": {
      "idle": [0, 24],
      "stun": [0, 0]
    },
    framerate: 24
  });
  drone = new createjs.Sprite(data, "idle");
```

Comment: Just a heads up that if you can, you should use a single image. This will be more performant on devices where it is using the GPU. Any time you change images, you can get into situations where you see small pauses when huge images are swapped.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by providing an extended `frames` array:

```
var data = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
  "images": ["images/Drones-Hovering-Loop-12fps.png", "image2.png"],
  "frames": [
    // x, y, width, height, imageIndex*, regX*, regY*
    [0, 0, 250, 262, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 250, 262, 1, 0, 0]
    //...
  ],
  "animations": {
    "idle": [0, 24],
    "stun": [0, 0]
  },
  framerate: 24
});
drone = new createjs.Sprite(data, "idle");
```

`imageIndex` (5th element in the frame array) is what you need to specify the image source. In my example #0 is `images/Drones-Hovering-Loop-12fps.png` and #1 is `image2.png`

Link to docs: http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/SpriteSheet.html

Comment: thanks, tried your example, but doesn't work for me. The sprite image keeps flickering

Comment: If you post the resulting code, someone may be able to help

Comment: this is the example that I followed the above in codepen
http://codepen.io/derr/pen/zrXXGz

Comment: As far as I can see, it works correctly. You have 2 sprites on different spritesheets and the animation shows them both. Although if you only have 2 frames, you should not set animation to 25 frames here: `"idle":[0, 24]`, change it to `"idle":[0,1]`.

Comment: not sure how it does but seems doesn't work as I follow closesly, is it suppose to work like under "idle" animation, it uses the Drones-Hovering-Loop-12fps.png.

while under "stun" animation, it uses the 02_Drones-(Flying-Left)(12fps).png

Comment: Ok, now I get it. You need to provied a separate array of frames for every spritesheet. I've made an example with `idle` animation on your codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPzLmw